# How to insert the value of another cell in excel not the formula

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet that changes regularly. I want to add a number of offset formulas that reference a particular cell as a starting point, however this first cell moves up or down the page. eg the starting point is `A20` one week, but next week it is at `A33` etc. I need to reference this cell further down the sheet.

So further down (in say cell `B302`) I would enter `=Offset(A20, 0, 0)` to get the start cell, then below that `(B303) =Offset(A20,1,0)`, then below that `=Offset(A20,2,0)` etc etc etc

But if `A20` changes all the time, how do I tell each offset formula where to start without changing every single one? I thought about writing `"A20"` in cell `B301`, then instead of using `"A20"` in Offset, I would equal the 'value' of `B301` (eg A20). That way I just need to change the value of `B301` each week instead of all the offset formulas. Is there a way to insert the string value of a cell, not the formula? eg `=Offset(B301,1,0)` - where `B301` equals `A20`, or `A33` etc etc?

Comment: Can't you just select all the cells containing Formula `Offset` and then use `Find And Replace` window to Find `A20` & Replace with `A33` ??

Comment: FYI there are many other formula's in the sheet so using find and replace would take considerable more time. Using INDIRECT worked like a charm though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 options for this :

**1st** - You can use **Find & replace** to change the Reference Cell.

**2nd** - You can write down the Reference cell number in a Cell and use **`indirect`** in all of the Functions `Offset`  to use that cell as reference. So you can change the value in that reference cell and the formulas will get updated automatically.

[image: Like in the Screenshot]

Comment: Fantastic! Indirect worked like a charm! This is exactly what I was trying to achieve!

Comment: Cool .. Accept this as an Answer then :) @PaulOmeara

Answer (score 0):

Create a name (eg) "REFCELL" and point it to A20.

Then you can use

```
=OFFSET(REFCELL,1,0) etc.
```

Later you can update the name to point to your new location.